# Do save penalties also apply to DCs?

Tags: saving-throw, pathfinder-2e, difficulty-class

If someone has a penalty to a save, does it automatically lower the matching DC?

[Bon Mot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2114) for example gives a penalty to *saves*:

> Critical Success: The target is distracted and takes a **–3 status penalty to** Perception and **Will saves** for 1 minute

If it is a critical success, and you try to Demoralize (Intimidation check against Will DC) the target, is the DC three lower?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

I believe it's stated explicitly somewhere but can't seem to find that at the moment. I'll update when I do, but until then we only have it implicitly in the various locations (here, [Saving Throws](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=328)) where modifier calculations are found.

> Will saving throws measure how well you can resist attacks to your mind and spirit. They use your Wisdom modifier and are calculated as shown in the formula below.
>
> **Will save result = d20 roll + Wisdom modifier + proficiency bonus + other bonuses + penalties**
>
> Sometimes you'll need to know your DC for a given saving throw. The DC for a saving throw is 10 + the total modifier for that saving throw.

Note that the DC is 'the total modifier' added to 10, and the modifier calculation includes penalties.

Comment: Why does reducing a will save also reduce your DC? Your class DC is 10 + prof + ability mod. Decreasing your will save doesn't touch any of those values. Formula here: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=102

Comment: @indigochild I'm speaking directly about (Will) Save DC, which has nothing (essentially) to do with Class DC